# 【NavigableString Does Not Have Find Method】Web Scraping LinkedIn Using Selenium

Tags: selenium, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

This is my first post in stack-overflow.

Straight to the point, I was trying to mimic this post:

[Extracting job information from LinkedIn Jobs using BeautifulSoup and Selenium](https://amandeepsaluja.com/extracting-job-information-from-linkedin-jobs-using-beautifulsoup-and-selenium/)

And I also want to sign up, and that is my code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/header/nav/div/a[2]").click()
sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="username"]""").send_keys("xxx")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="password"]""").send_keys("xxx")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="app__container"]/main/div[2]/form/div[3]/button""").click()
sleep(5)

driver.get(url) 

sleep(5)
```

So far so good. However, when I reach this code:
"for job in job_container:"
The job has a type of NavigableString, but it should be a Tag.

My suspicion is that this line didn't read the correct tag:

```
job_container = lxml_soup.find('ul', class_ = 'jobs-search-results__list list-style-none')
```

But I am not sure what is correct.

Can someone help me, please? Thank you.

Comment: You need to post enough code to reproduce the problem. Have a read through [mcve].

Comment: Also: webscraping LinkedIn (or any site) without permission is likely to get you blacklisted. You might want to have a look at https://www.linkedin.com/developers/

Comment: Hi SiKing, Basically my code is mimicking this post https://amandeepsaluja.com/extracting-job-information-from-linkedin-jobs-using-beautifulsoup-and-selenium/ but adding a feature of signing in username and password. Then the program seems not working. Also, the data I am collecting is public data. And according to Forbs, "A court has ruled that it's legal to scrape publicly available data from LinkedIn, despite the company's claims that this violates user privacy". Thank you for your concerns.

Comment: Can you share the relevant html?

Comment: Hi, QHarr, Yes, it is from this link https://amandeepsaluja.com/extracting-job-information-from-linkedin-jobs-using-beautifulsoup-and-selenium/

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I add one more line before the for loop, and it works:

```
job_container = job_container.find_all('li', class_ = 'jobs-search-results__list-item')
```

Don't know why, it just does.